# Why does Yor call Loid as Loid-san when with others?

Tags: japanese-language, culture, japan, spy-x-family

I thought it was part of [Yor's politeness trope](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67013/why-does-yor-call-anya-as-anya-san-instead-of-anya-chan), but this is what ConMan said:

> To each other, probably just Loid-san. When I said she would call him anata, I was thinking more in the situations where they need to play up their relationship in front of others, like Yor's brother.

I checked again the 1st episode and indeed Yor does call Loid as Loid-san in front of people.

Guess: Maybe it was a mistake on Yor's part because Yor needed Loid to pretend to be a boyfriend but then Loid made a mistake in the 1st place in saying that Loid was Yor's husband instead?

Or idk is it a common thing in Japan for spouses to call each other -san?

> [Normally, firstname-san would require some kind of relationship between the speaker and the addressed (e.g. wife and husband).](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93904/how-does-last-name-kun-chan-compare-to-1st-name-san)

So ConMan is wrong?

Also I checked S01E08 when Yuri (Yor's brother) actually DOES show up. Yor says explicitly: 'I just call him Loid-san.'

Note: I'm adding the Japan tag based on [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66508/is-it-common-to-tell-people-how-you-spell-your-name-in-japan), [this](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4542/should-the-japan-tag-be-used-in-this-death-note-question) and [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70362).

Comment: I don't understand why this kind of questions get downvotes...

Comment: @JimmyYang see [Is it ok to overanalyze an anime?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/is-it-ok-to-overanalyze-an-anime/4513#4513)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be partly due to Yor's politeness, but it is perfectly common for a husband and a wife to call each other by first name-san.

According to [a poll](https://cancam.jp/archives/708555), it is the second commonest from wife to husband and the commonest from husband to wife. The bold one is FN-san.

> Q.家の中で、ご主人のことをどのように呼んでいますか？ (How do you call Husband)　
> ニックネーム　39.0％（649名）　
> **名前にさん・くんなどを付ける　34.8％（579名）**　
> 名前を呼び捨て　14.5％（241名）　
> パパ・お父さんなど　4.9％（81名）　
> ねい、おい、おまえなど　3.2％（53名）　
> あなた　1.2％（20名）　
> その他　2.4％（40名）

> Q.家の中で、ご主人にどのように呼ばれていますか？ (How are you called by Husband) 
> **名前にちゃん・さんを付ける　32.2％（536名）**
> 名前を呼び捨て　30.4％（505名）
> ニックネーム　27.0％（449名）
> ママ・お母さんなど　3.8％（64名）
> ねえ、おい、おまえなど　2.8％（47名）
> あなた　1.5％（25名）
> その他　2.2％（37名）

In Japan, it is legally not (yet) possible for a married couple to have different surnames, so using last name is generally out of question (even though it may happen due to the pre-marriage habit in individual cases). Considering the manga is written in Japanese, using first name-san between Yor and Loid is simply a normal choice.

Comment: Wait...is there a way we can break down that poll between the san and the kun? For all we know it's 30% kun and 2.2 or 4.8% san?

Comment: @BCLC No, I think it aggregates kun/san/chan. Generally it is usually about the age. FN-san will be for all ages, but kun/chan for younger couples. I feel it odd if 40+ year olds call each other by kun/chan though there may exist such couples. Note that today people get married for the first time in Japan around 30.

Comment: oohhhhh thanks that makes a lot of sense. depends on what age they get married eg at 25 vs at 35 and in the case of loid and yor they got married in what late 20s mid 30s and that's (partly) why yor calls loid as loid-san (in front of others as well as in private) ?

Comment: @BCLC It is more like just a default, considering how they met. Using chan/kun would look too friendly. Their character being generally modest may play a role, too.

Comment: ok makes a lot of sense. thanks sundowner. Please consider editing that into your answer.