# Why does Yuni change between Mineaki-san and Mine-kun? (S01E05)

Tags: japanese-language, my-stepmoms-daughter-is-my-ex

You can either answer based on the series or guess based on knowledge about general Japanese culture / language.

In S01E01: Yuni addresses Mineaki as Mineaki-san.

(slightly NSFW)

> [image]

In S01E05: Yuni addresses Mineaki as Mine-kun after Yume and Mizuto give Yuni a mother's day present.

[image]

The only relevant difference I see here is that Yuni knows Yume and Mizuto are around for S01E05. (In S01E01, Yuni doesn't necessarily know that Yume and Mizuto are on the 1st floor of the house.)

---

Maybe related: [Why does Yor call Loid as Loid-san when with others?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67028/why-does-yor-call-loid-as-loid-san-when-with-others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the poll in the linked answer shows, using a nick name and first name-san are both common (although Mine-kun is a bit mix of these).

> Q.家の中で、ご主人のことをどのように呼んでいますか？ (How do you call Husband)
>
> - ニックネーム　39.0％（649名）
> - 名前にさん・くんなどを付ける　34.8％（579名）

So, I would say it is simply a variation of Yuni's calling her husband. That is, Yuni uses either way from time to time, without much reason. I suppose something similar happens in English, like the same person calling *John* by *Johnny* etc. (Not sure it applies particularly to John/Johnny, but I mean, people do call each other by different versions of the name sometimes)

If anything, when they are talking about a serious topic, first name-san would be used; nick name sounds more casual.

Comment: John & Johnny? Hmmm...ok I guess. There is Jimmy and Jimbo in Jimmy Neutron. So yeah. Lol. Thanks.